# Are IR signals affected by nearby atoms?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy

E.g. If there is a methyl from an aldehyde vs a methyl at the end of a hydrocarbon chain, will the difference in neighboring atoms have an effect on the location of the IR signal?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why are you trying to perform structure determination from IR? You get much more information generally if you just use NMR or GCMS.

Comment: It's more about whether it is possible to obtain this information than an interest in practical use.

Comment: Not so sure about IR, but near-edge x-ray absorption fine structure (NEXAFS) is certainly a well known technique in surface science for determining relative atomic positions precisely through interference of the surrounding atoms on the x-ray emission.

Comment: It's not really practical to do this via IR. IR works on bond lengths. So if the difference is negligible, instrument noise is going to dwarf anything useful you'll pull out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was [already said](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60279/are-ir-signals-affected-by-nearby-atoms#comment102088_60279),

> IR works on bond lengths. So if the difference is negligible, instrument noise is going to dwarf anything useful you'll pull out.

There *will* be a difference, and you can definitely detect it computationally, but by normal experimental means (benchtop FT-IR or ATR, not a gas-phase experiment) background noise might the same order of magnitude as any frequency shift you'd see.

For example, the carbonyl stretching frequency and carbonyl bond lengths calculated using B97-D/6-31G(d):

$$
\newcommand{\AA}{\unicode{x212B}}
\begin{array}{llll}
           & \text{bond length} \, (\AA) & \text{frequency, calc.} \, (\text{cm}^{-1}) & \text{frequency, expt.} \, (\text{cm}^{-1}) \\ \hline
\text{pentanal}   & 1.218 & 1772 & 1727 \\
\text{2-hexanone} & 1.223 & 1753 & 1718
\end{array}
$$

Technically, you can distinguish between these in an experiment, but one would be more interested in the presence/absence of a large aldehyde band. This works due to the sharpness of the carbonyl stretch.

Closer to what I think you're asking about is the influence on vibrational frequencies of groups *far* from the area of substitution. These particular examples are tough because the normal modes of hydrocarbon-like species tend to couple the motion of many $\ce{C-H}$ stretches together. With that in mind, here are the highest-frequency $\ce{C-H}$ stretching modes, which happen to belong to the terminal $\ce{CH3}$ groups. The bond length is for the hydrogen eclipsed with the carbonyl.

$$
\newcommand{\AA}{\unicode{x212B}}
\begin{array}{lll}
           & \text{bond length} \, (\AA) & \text{frequency, calc.} \, (\text{cm}^{-1}) \\ \hline
\text{pentanal}   & 1.102 & 3044 \\
\text{2-hexanone} & 1.102 & 3038
\end{array}
$$

"Wow, that's amazing, you *can* resolve it!" Not this time. Compare the full spectra for pentanal/valeraldehyde (top) and 2-hexanone (bottom) and try to perform the peak assignment. Is it it the 2960/2962 pair? 2935/2936?

[image]
[image]

Experimental values/images taken from the [Spectral Database for Organic Compounds](http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_index.cgi?lang=eng).